# Some regex expressions do not work on my notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to search any 4 digit number in notepad++ when i try `\d{4}` it does not work. Same thing with `\b` does not work on my notepad++(version 5.9.6.2)

Comment: try \d\d\d\d. http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions

Comment: That works. my worry is that some of these regex does not work....do we have an alternative for \b look behind assertions don't work either...

Comment: Works here, did you remember to switch ON the radio button "Regular expression" at the bottom-left of the search panel ? Aren't you at the end of the file with a "down" direction search ?

Comment: I am not an advocate but better use Sublime text, it is awesome for that purpose. Also allows the ussage of `$1` for the replacement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notepad++ version 5.9.6.2 is an antique. Version 7.4.x is now available.

There were major improvements to regular expression handing in, I believe, the version 6.x series. regular expressions with `...{4}` and `\b` work fine in the 6.x.x and 7.x.x versions.

Comment: Yup. Thank you. I have been able to work with {} \b etc on the newer version.

Comment: @akshay Has your question been answered? If not then please edit it to explain what further is needed. If it has been answered then please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer